# Laravel 5.3 - InvalidArgumentException View [index] not found

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, routes, laravel-blade

I **already deployed** my Laravel app into my **VPS**. It works fine on localhost. I think the error is in my routes or maybe the controller because the path is still going into my local machine directory (see error message line 2) but I really can't see the problem in the code.

I have tried using `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:cache` but it still doesn't work. It still refers to my local machine directory.

This is the directory of index.blade.php

```
Root
|-- portofolio
    |-- app
    |-- bootstrap
    |-- config
    |-- database
    |-- resources
        |-- assets
        |-- lang
        |-- views
            |-- index.blade.php
    |-- routes
    |-- storage
    |-- tests
    |-- vendor
|-- public_html
    |-- css
    |-- img
    |-- js
    |-- vendor
```

This is the **Route**

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'Portofolio@link']);
```

This is the **Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Portofolio extends Controller
{
public function link() {

    $categories = [
        '1' => 'Print Design',
        '2' => 'Logo Design',
        '3' => 'Web Design',
        '4' => 'Product Design',
        '5' => 'Character Design',
        '6' => 'Packaging Design'
    ];

    $projects = [
        '1' => 'IMSAA Training Certificate',
        '2' => 'Rusticity Logo',
        '3' => 'Handy Production Website',
        '4' => 'Nihon no Matsuri Bag Project',
        '5' => 'The Chin - Captain Jack Sparrow',
        '6' => 'Rusticity Packaging'
    ];

    $images = [
        '1' => '1',
        '2' => '2',
        '3' => '3',
        '4' => '4',
        '5' => '5',
        '6' => '6'
    ];

    $skills = [
        '1' => 'Photoshop',
        '2' => 'Ms. Office',
        '3' => 'Laravel',
        '4' => 'PHP',
        '5' => 'HTML',
        '6' => 'MySQL'
    ];

    $points = [
        '1' => '80%',
        '2' => '90%',
        '3' => '60%',
        '4' => '60%',
        '5' => '60%',
        '6' => '60%'
    ];

    return view('index')->withCategories($categories)->withProjects($projects)->withImages($images)->withSkills($skills)->withPoints($points);
}
}
```

This is the error message (see line 2)

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:

View [index] not found.

1.  in FileViewFinder.php line 137
2.  at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('E:\Laravel\portofolio\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
3.  at FileViewFinder->find('index') in Factory.php line 174
4.  at Factory->make('index', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 856
5.  at view('index') in Portofolio.php line 56
6.  at Portofolio->link()
7.  at call_user_func_array(array(object(Portofolio), 'link'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
8.  at Controller->callAction('link', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
9.  at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Portofolio), 'link') in Route.php line 190
10. at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
11. at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
12. at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
13. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
14. at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
15. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
16. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
17. at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
18. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
19. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
20. at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
21. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
22. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
23. at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
24. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
25. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
26. at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
27. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
28. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
29. at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
30. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
31. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
32. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
33. at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
34. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
35. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
36. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
37. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
38. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
39. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
40. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
41. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
42. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
43. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: What is your resource/view folder/file structure

Comment: Check the path of the `index` file.

Comment: where is you index.blade.php????

Comment: your index.blade.php should be inside the resources/views/
 folder

Comment: Yes, my index.blade.php is in the resources/views folder

Comment: And to be more clear, This error happened when I deploy it on my VPS and it works fine on localhost

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I have solved the problem.**

The problem is that my server is not being set up properly because the domain doesn't connect properly to my VPS. Contacted the hosting provider and the problem was solved.

If anyone have this problem just check

1. Have you already done `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan config:clear`?
2. Did you name your view correctly as `yourview.blade.php`?
3. Did you place the view correctly in `resources\views`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the index.blade.php in the views dir, here the index.blade.php is not the index.php in the / dir.

Comment: Yes, its in the views directory

Comment: and to be more clear, This error happened when I deploy it on my VPS and it works fine on localhost

Comment: check your apache conf for root dir